# Uploading with NestJS and Multer doesn't work

Tags: node.js, typescript, upload, nestjs, multer

I'm trying to upload files with nesteJS and Multer according to this documentation : https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/file-upload

In my app.module file I have the following configuration::

[image]

In the controller of my module I have this method create one I want to receive the file in the method post post:

[image]

The problem is that when I send the form-data with a file and a description, the description works but the file doesn't... What could be wrong?

[image]